# How to subset xts object by end of quarter dates by sequence number?

Tags: r, subset, xts

I'm trying to extract end-of-quarter data from a large xts object based on the numerical location and I'm at a loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated. As an example, let's say I have a year of data as follows:

```
set.seed(78)
date.a <-seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2000/12/31"), "days")
dat <-xts(rnorm(length(date.a)), date.a)

head(dat)
                 [,1]
2000-01-01  0.7172775
2000-01-02  0.2581460
2000-01-03  1.0750581
2000-01-04 -0.5375775
2000-01-05 -1.3264418
2000-01-06  1.1817348
```

I can easily extract end-of-quarter dat manually, such as:

```
a <-dat[91]
b <-dat[182]  
c <-dat[274]
d <-dat[366]

c(a,b,c,d)
                 [,1]
2000-03-31  0.7329080
2000-06-30  1.0648634
2000-09-30 -3.1556240
2000-12-31  0.9452281
```

How can I programatically extract these dates/data? The challenge is figuring out how the numerical sequence plays out over the course of several years or decades. Since the interval isn't going to be a standard ~91 days, it's unclear how to proceed. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `c` is a poor choice of variable name because of its other significance in R, but it will technically work.  Tread carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a vector of dates `d` and refer to the xts elements as `dat[d]`.

Here's how I would do it (I like to use the `lubridate` package, and I like to emulate the `EOMonth` function from Excel):

```
library(lubridate)
EOMonth = function(d, step) {
  day(d) = 1 # just in case we inadvertantly compute 30 February or 31 April.
  month(d) = month(d) + step
  day(d) = days_in_month(d)
  return(d)
}
d = EOMonth(ymd("1999-12-31"), seq(from = 3, to = 12, by = 3))
dat[d]
```

If you need the indices, you could then do something like this:

```
all.d = ymd("1999-12-31") + 1:366
answer = which(all.d %in% d)
```

Comment: lebelinoz, that's an elegant solution and it works fine to extract the a,b,c,d examples I show. But for reasons that aren't worth explaining, I need the numerical IDs for those dates, i.e., the "91" in dat[91], the "182" in dat[182] in my example above.

Comment: One small glitch, however, is that the number of days between end of quarters varies a bit over several years. There's probably a fix, of course. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: My EOMonth method should compensate for that. Doesn't it?

Comment: It does in the year I present as an example, but other years don't always match up with the sequence, which is to say sometimes an end of quarter ends on the 28th, 29th, 30th, or 31st, depending on the calendar.

Comment: It should still work.  Set `d = EOMonth(ymd("1999-12-31"), seq(from = 3, to = 17 * 12, by = 3))` and `all.d = ymd("1999-12-31") + 1:(17*366)`, and you'll get all the quarterly indices for the past 17 years.  If your quarter end-dates are business dates (i.e. take the previous Friday if they fall on a weekend), you can modify `EOMonth` and `all.d` accordingly, but that's not the case with your sample data.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks again!

Comment: @lebelinoz _Given_ that you have hardcoded startdate and quarters, you could just use `%m+%`: `ymd("1999-12-31") %m+% months(seq(from = 3, to = 12, by = 3))`

Answer (score 2):

You may convert the dates to `zoo::yearqtr`. Then convert the `yearqtr` back to `Date` while setting `frac = 1`, i.e. the last date in each quarter (see `?yearmon`). Use these dates to subset your data:

```
dat[index(dat) == as.Date(as.yearqtr(index(dat)), frac = 1)]
#                 [,1]
# 2000-03-31  0.7329080
# 2000-06-30  1.0648634
# 2000-09-30 -3.1556240
# 2000-12-31  0.9452281
```

Comment: Henrik, your suggestion offers the basis for a useful alternative approach. Thanks much!

Comment: @JamesPicerno Thank you for your feedback. Glad to hear you found it helpful. `zoo` has indeed many convenient functions.